# RxSwift: implementing concatMap generating Reentrancy anomaly was detected error

Tags: rx-swift, xcode11, concatmap, ios13.2, swift5

I'm trying to implement `concatMap` within `RxSwift` but when I tried to set a new value to the observable within the `concatMap` I'm getting this error:

```
Reentrancy anomaly was detected.
  > Debugging: To debug this issue you can set a breakpoint in /Users/SuperUser/repos/RxObserver/Pods/RxSwift/RxSwift/Rx.swift:96 and observe the call stack.
  > Problem: This behavior is breaking the observable sequence grammar. `next (error | completed)?`
    This behavior breaks the grammar because there is overlapping between sequence events.
    Observable sequence is trying to send an event before sending of previous event has finished.
  > Interpretation: This could mean that there is some kind of unexpected cyclic dependency in your code,
    or that the system is not behaving in the expected way.
  > Remedy: If this is the expected behavior this message can be suppressed by adding `.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)`
    or by enqueuing sequence events in some other way.
```

Here is my code:

```
public let myNumbers = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    processNumbers()
    myNumbers.accept("one")
    myNumbers.accept("two")
}

func processNumbers() {
    Observable.of(myNumbers).concatMap{ $0
    }.subscribe(onNext:{
        print($0)
        if $0 == "one" || $0 == "two"{
            self.myNumbers.accept("YEAH!")
        }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

}
```

Any of you know why I am getting this error or how can I change my implementation to avoid getting this error/warning?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Any of you knows why I may getting this error?

```
  > Problem: This behavior is breaking the observable sequence grammar. `next (error | completed)?`
    This behavior breaks the grammar because there is overlapping between sequence events.
    Observable sequence is trying to send an event before sending of previous event has finished.
```

> how can change my implementation to avoid getting this error/warning ?

```
  > Remedy: If this is the expected behavior this message can be suppressed by adding `.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)`
    or by enqueuing sequence events in some other way.
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to fix this issue:

```
func processNumbers() {
        Observable.of(myNumbers).concatMap{ $0
        }
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
        .subscribe(onNext:{
            print($0)
            if $0 == "one" || $0 == "two"{
                self.myNumbers.accept("YEAH!")
            }
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }
```

By adding this line of code `.observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)` the error/warning goes away!!